# node js jasmine testing

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to test the server side of my website with jasmine node.js

```
 it("Logs you out", function (done){
    request("http://localhost:43030/logout", function(error, response, body){
        expect(body).toBe("You have successfully logged out);
        done();
    });
});
```

the output is:

```
Stacktrace:
     Error: Expected '{
  "isVerified": false,
  "meta": {
    "description": "You have successfully logged out.",
    "timestamp": "2014-01-17T12:37:54.500Z"
  }
```

How can i get the value of the meta description?

```
 expect(body.description).toBe("You have successfully logged out); ?
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the response, but shouldn't it be:

```
expect(body.meta.description).toBe("You have successfully logged out.");
```